# Emacs Dired rename many files

Tags: emacs, dired

How to rename from:

```
VAR1_1F_text.txt
VAR2_1F_text.txt
VAR3_2F_text.txt
```

to

```
1F_VAR1_text.txt
1F_VAR2_text.txt
2F_VAR3_text.txt
```

How to switch parts of filenames?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

This can easily be done using `dired`:

1. Enter a dired view of your directory
2. Switch to writable dired mode (`wdired-change-to-wdired-mode`): <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-q</kbd>
3. Edit the file names listing as if it were a normal buffer (for example using a keyboard macro or a rectangular selection or query-replace). Here is a regexp-based solution:

   <kbd>C-M-%</kbd>`\(VAR.\)_\(..\)`<kbd>RET</kbd>`\2_\1`<kbd>RET</kbd>
4. Finish editing (`wdired-finish-edit`): <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-s</kbd> or <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-c</kbd>

You're done!

Comment: You can also do it without WDired, just mark files you need with `m` (or `* s` to mark all files in buffer) and run `% R` to rename with regexp.

Comment: The wdired method is a bit easier to work with b/c if you have something like `run-foo.sh`, `foo.conf` and `init-foo-script` and you wanted to replace foo with bar, it is simpler to just do a replace in the buffer than concoct a regex that matches the correct value and properly replaces it. That said, in the described scenario, % R does seem like it'd work just fine.

Comment: Is there nothing emacs can't do?

Comment: How could I possibly have missed WDired for 20 years? Such a time saver!  Thank you, @Francesco

Comment: Just if anyone uses `spacemacs` you can enter the `wdired-change-to-wdired-mode` using 
`<leader> b w`  as in (buffer write)
my `<leader>` is `space` for Evil mode.

Answer (score 4):

You could also use Magnar Sveen's multiple-cursors from here, [github link](https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el).

Switch to writable dired, select the files you want to rename, `M-x` `mc/edit-lines`.
This should create multiple cursor each with its own kill history.

Answer (score 1):

This technique, which I discovered on the internet, is highly beneficial. It enables you to perform various actions with emacs macros, including editing text files.

Basically what you see as text file save with C-x C-s.

```
Alt+x dired to go to the directory.
Alt+x dired-toggle-read-only 【Ctrl+x Ctrl+q】.
Then, just edit the file names. (You can use Alt+x query-replace or Alt+x query-replace-regexp [see Emacs: Find Replace in Current File] or rectangle commands. [see Emacs: Edit Column Text, Rectangle Commands])
When done, wdired-finish-edit 【Ctrl+c Ctrl+c】 to commit the changes.
```

To abort, Alt+x w dired-abort-changes 【Ctrl+c Ctrl+k】

Reference: http://xahlee.info/emacs/emacs/rename_file_pattern.html